# Comments at end of line in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, comments

When we define an enum type, we may need some comments for each case.

I know we can have a comments syntax like this in Obj-C:

```
enum Example
{
    Example1,    ///< Comments for Example1. 
    Example2,    ///< Comments for Example2. 
    Example3.    ///< Comments for Example3. 
}
```

My question is: How to do this in swift?

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough...
Put code and comments at the same line, code at the start of line and comments at the end of line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use double stars to show the comment at a summary:

```
enum Example {

    /** Comments for Example1. (with stars) */
    case example1

    /// Comments for Example2. (with three slash)
    case example2

    /// Comments for Example3. (with three slash)
    case example3
}
```

here is a [reference](https://nshipster.com/swift-documentation/)

Comment: It works but not so beautiful for some simple definitions.

Comment: my opinion if it's simple then you shouldn't add it

Comment: Instead of `/**` you can use `///` too. But it has to be above the case.

Comment: @坤哥你好 do you thank that with `///` it looks better by the way you are free to check the reference at the end of the answer

Comment: @zombie, you can add both options in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of unclear what your question is - adding "//" will make the rest of the code on that line a comment. So you should do:

```
enum Example
{
    Example1,    // Comments for Example1. 
    Example2,    // Comments for Example2. 
    Example3.    // Comments for Example3. 
}
```

Or, you could just do it how you did with obj-c. Both should work fine.

Comment: comments start with "//" won't shown in quick help, that's the problem...